# Unable to get the messages from cloud AMQP queue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, sails.js, cloudamqp

Hi i am trying to use rabbitmq in my sails app. when I try to post data in my model after giving the connections adapter I can see the data received in my rabbit queue but the database has not created.
I'm using mongo database for my models and sails-rabbitmq as my node_module
I referred [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-rabbitmq) link

```
npm install sails-rabbitmq
```

The connection adapter is -

```
rabbitCluster: {
adapter: 'sails-rabbitmq',
//my amqp rabbitmq installation url
url: 'amqp://localhost',
},



MongoDB: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017,
user: '',
password: '',
database: 'myTest'
 }
```

inside my model specified the connection as follow

```
connection : ['rabbitCluster','MongoDB']

//in my config/rabbitmq.js file
module.exports.rabbitmq = {
    pkFormat: 'string'
};
```

as I understand we don't need to write create and update controller methods it should work with default CRUD operations provided by sails. but i get no response when i try to create a database entry.